# $(..).filterizr is not a function & does it have anything to do with package-lock.json

Tags: json, wordpress, plugins, npm, package

Hi I'm including a gallery plugin called Filterizr for my wordpress theme and NPM installed it and got is as a dependancy

PACKAGE.JSON

```
 "dependencies": {
  "filterizr": "^1.2.5"
 },
```

But I have also been getting a package-lock.json recently and wonder if it has anything to do with it. I also ran into problem using Angular CDN and saw a package-lock.json as well.

I am running my instantiating filterizr in main.js

```
 (function($){
     $('.filtr-container').filterizr();
 //Filterz


 })(jQuery);
```

My package-lock.json has my filterized plugin as well

PACKGE-LOCK.JSON

```
},
"filterizr": {
  "version": "1.2.5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/filterizr/-/filterizr-1.2.5.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-sOUe51rH5GQxrhRFkUmpJXeWAuw="
},
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add your `main.js` code as well, or any file where you have referenced to all your JS files for minification.

Comment: I did, I'm using Gulp Minifier and I have my main.js there as well

Answer (score -1):

If you are building a simple static website and you are already importing jQuery yourself, make sure to download the /dist/jquery.filterizr.min.js and simply import it after jQuery.